# Php, how to determine if a class (and not taking account subclasses!) has a method?

Tags: php, oop

I know theres a method_exists() but it says true even when that method is inherited.

```
class A
{
 public function eix()
 {
 }
}

class B extends A
{
}
```

echo method_exists ('B', 'eix');

so its true, but B class doesnt have it. How to dodge this?

Comment: The class B inheritted properties from class A, so B have the function eix, is it? i think so

Comment: Class B does have it. 
Because it inherent it from A.

If your struggling with that, might be an indicator that you should reconsider your architectural design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use reflection to achieve this.  Look into the [`ReflectionMethod`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php) class and you'll find the [`getDeclaringClass`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.getdeclaringclass.php) method.

```
$classname = 'B';
$methodname = 'eix';

$method = new ReflectionMethod($classname, $methodname);
$declaringclass = $method->getDeclaringClass();

if ($classname == $declaringclass->name) {
    // method was defined on the original class
}
```

That said, the key point is that class `B` *does* have a method `eix`, since it inherits all `A`'s methods that it doesn't redefine. I can't quite work out a circumstance where you'd need to know where the method was defined, but this technique allows you to do so if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Use [get_parent_class()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-parent-class.php) to identify the parent, and then use method_exists() against that.

```
echo method_exists (get_parent_class('B'), 'eix');
```

Comment: That would work in this example, so your answer is valid. Nonetheless, you'll run into problems if both A and B have a method with the same name (`B::foo()` overwrites `A::foo()`).

Answer (score 0):

Since class B extends class A it inherent all of its methods and `method_exists()` will always return true.

Question is why you would need to know whether the method is first created in class A or class B? I see no reason for why one would need this information.

And if this is a problem, you should probably reconsider your architectural design from the start.

But just as *Mark Baker* explains, one could probably find out at least if the method exist in parent class as well, doesn't necessarily mean it haven't been overridden in the child class.

```
if(method_exists(get_parent_class('B'), 'eix'))
{
  //Exist in parent class and was not first created in this. 
  //But still is inherent to this.
}
else 
{
  //Doesn't exist in parent and must been created in this.
}
```